# Fast Euclidean distance calculation between nodes of a graph

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, graph, euclidean-distance

I have a graph with a list of edges and coordinates of its nodes. For example,

```
import numpy as np
edge = np.random.randint(100, size=[100,2])
node = np.random.rand(100,2)
```

I need to find the length of all edges. So far, I have been using the following function (my best shot!) which works quite well but not for very large graphs:

```
def GetLengths(node, edge):
    li = node[edge]
    arr = np.linalg.norm(li[:,0]-li[:,1],axis=1)
    return arr, np.mean(arr)
```

Is there any other implementation that works better (=faster)? I mostly work in two-dimension, but I appreciate methods that can be generalized to higher dimensions.

Comment: Look at the functions in `scipy.spatial.distance`, specifically `cdist` and `pdist`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I know about them but `cdist` calculates distance of all pairs. `pdist` calculates distance of all elements of an array.

Comment: What do you need the euclidean distance for? Would the squared euclidean distance work instead?

Comment: @ali_m: Mostly force calculation, considering edges are springs which is related to the distance not its squared!

Comment: Could you give some more context for the problem you are trying to solve? `np.linalg.norm` is already pretty fast, especially for higher-dimensional inputs. You could do a little better, but I don't think there's a great deal of room for major improvements just in the distance calculation itself. Are you iterating over nodes? Could you vectorize your distance calculation over multiple nodes?

Comment: This is a "geometric graph theory" problem that a graph is made of springs. If springs are compressed/stretched, they interact via a force which is a function of edge lengths. The first step to calculate forces is having all distances. Once I have the lengths, I use another vectorized function to calculate the forces.
I agree that `np.linalg.norm` is pretty fast. But I have optimized all other parts of the code and the bottleneck is now "distance calculation". I even tried to cythonize the distance calculation but it didn't help that much!

Comment: have you compared it to einsum?   for example given an array, of origins and destinations...
    diff = orig - dest  
    dist = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',diff,diff))

Comment: @DanPatterson: Yes, but `np.einsum` is only marginally faster.

Comment: I think you should show us a larger chunk of your code. You're unlikely to see anything more than marginal performance gains if you focus exclusively on the distance calculation.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you want to find *all* edge lengths, don't write your own function that just finds one edge length at a time.  Instead, make a numpy array that has the point pairs you want, and then pass the entire array to `cdist` and it will calculate all of them quite quickly.

Comment: My favorite method is pairwise_distances from scikit-learn... You can use any distance method... Also, you can use n_jobs parameter for parallel run: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html

Comment: @Mahdi - Maybe show your Cython code. With [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org) I was able to get a ~10x speedup.